# Search form on jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

i have html css js web-site and i have a little problem. I make html and css for my search_form. I need to scroll the site page to a current product when user enters the product name in the search engine.
I suggest that when i'm inputting product name with class .text_2_Rapid_Item_1 my page is scrolling before product .Rapid_Item_1 with product name .text_2_Rapid_Item_1. How can i do that?

```
// scroll to current product (it didn't work)
$(function () {
  $(".text_2_Rapid_Item_1").on("input", function () {
    $(".Rapid_Item_1").get(0).scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to ask that when a new product is added the page should scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Neha Soni, when product name is added to input form.

Comment: Yes, I asked the same. So you want to scroll the page, is it?

Comment: I need scroll page when user input product name in input_form.

Comment: Are you using any api or typeahead ? for get the product and select.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. To show the menu in visible area and for search using innerText

```
<ul class="nav metis-menu" id="side-menu">
   <li class="sales">
      <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-text">
        Sales                
        </span>
        <span class="fa arrow pleft5"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" aria-expanded="false">
         <li class="order_list">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-sticky-note menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="sub-menu-text">
                Order                        
                </span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="sales_channel">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-tasks menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="sub-menu-text">
                channel                        
                </span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="trade_discount">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-percent menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="sub-menu-text">
                    Trade                        
                </span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="sales_diary_sync">
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner menu-icon"></i>
            <span class="sub-menu-text">
            Diary sync                        
        </span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item-dashboard">
      <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-text">
        Dashboard                
        </span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the jquery part of the above HTML

```
$(function() {
    $('#side-menu ').prepend("<li><input id='searchmenu' class='form-control'  placeholder='Search Menu' type='text' /></li>");
    $('aside li').click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem('menustay', $(this).attr("class"));
    });
    var strart = localStorage.getItem('menustay');
    var array = strart.split(' ');

    var toFindStr = array[0];
    var $scrollTo = $('aside');
    var $container = $scrollTo[0].children[0].children;
    for(var i=0; i<$container.length; i++){
        if(toFindStr == $container[i].classList[0]){
            var findst = $('li.' + toFindStr);
            if(findst[0].offsetTop != 0)
                var offsetdata = findst[0].offsetTop;
            else             
                var offsetdata = findst[1].offsetTop;
            
            var y = $('#side-menu').scrollTop();
            $('#side-menu').animate({ scrollTop: y + (offsetdata - 200) }, 50) 
        }
    }
    
    $('#searchmenu').on('keyup', function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<$container.length; i++){
            $('li.' + $container[i].classList[0]).css('display', 'none');
            $('#setup-menu-item').css('display', 'none');
            $('#searchmenu').css('display', 'block');
            if(data.target.value == ''){                
                $('li.' + $container[i].classList[0]).css('display', 'block');
                $('#setup-menu-item').css('display', 'none');
                $('#searchmenu').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else if($container[i].innerText.toLowerCase().search(data.target.value) > -1){
                $('li.' + $container[i].classList[0]).css('display', 'block');
                $('#setup-menu-item').css('display', 'block');
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Albin C S, can you show me, how can i do that in my situation with my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you using normal input and wants move the particular place based on value then use below code. but there is cons if having similar text on page. so suggesting to use typeahead and while select value from typeahead you can pick product and move the place (instead of on change input).

```
    $(".text_2_Rapid_Item_1").on("input", function () {
      if($(document).find("."+$(this).val()).length > 0){

       // try $("."+$(this).val()).scrollIntoView({ or get(0)

       $("."+$(this).val()).get(0).scrollIntoView({
         block: "start",
         behavior: "smooth",
       });
      } 
    });
```

Comment: I was trying to apply your code to my project, but it isn't working. I have never use typeahead before.

Comment: have you tried with $("."+$(this).val()).scrollIntoView({   or $("."+$(this).val())[0].scrollIntoView({   ??

Comment: Yes, unfortunately nothing.